# error:expected primary-expression before ',' token //function call

Tags: c++, linked-list

I could not figure this out looking at problems with similar errors.

I have a node class that was given to me, and I am supposed to implement a sort.  I believe I have the sort part working, but I am not sure how to start the linked list in my main. The list_head_insert seemed like it would work, but I get an error trying to call it.

```
// CONSTRUCTOR
node(
    const value_type& init_data = value_type( ),
    node* init_link = NULL
)
{ data_field = init_data; link_field = init_link; }
    private:
    value_type data_field;
    node* link_field;
void list_head_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry);
```

Here is my attempted call:

```
node head;
int temp;
list_head_insert(head&, temp);
```

This gives me an error:
expected primary-expression before ',' token
on the line where I call list_head_insert

I've been at this for hours trying to find a solution, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a pointer because the function requires an lvalue reference.

```
node head;
node* phead = &head;
int temp;
list_head_insert(phead, temp);
```

Comment: I had tried that already, it gives me this error: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'main_savitch_5::node*&' from an rvalue of type 'main_savitch_5::node*'|

Comment: Since it wants a reference you'll have to create one beforehand. Check my edit.